# How to avoid or skip error 400 in python while calling the API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop, error-handling

Note:- I have written my code after referring to few examples in stack overflow but still could not get the required output

I have a python script in which loop iterates with an Instagram API. I give the user_id as an input to the API which gets the no of posts, no of followers and no of following. Each time it gets a response, I load it into a JSON schema and append to lists data1, data2 and data3.

The issue is:= Some accounts are private accounts and the API call is not allowed to it. When I run the script in IDLE Python shell, its gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#144>", line 18, in <module>
beta=json.load(url)
File "C:\Users\rnair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-  packages\simplejson-3.8.2-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\simplejson\__init__.py", line 455,  in load
 return loads(fp.read(),
File "C:\Users\rnair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
**ValueError: read of closed file**
```

But the JSON contains this:-

```
{
  "meta":  {
  "error_type": "APINotAllowedError",
  "code": 400,
  "error_message": "you cannot view this resource"
 }
}
```

My code is:-

```
for r in range(307,601):
 var=r,sheet.cell(row=r,column=2).value
 xy=var[1]
 ij=str(xy)
 if xy=="Account Deleted":
    data1.append('null')
    data2.append('null')
    data3.append('null')
    continue
myopener=Myopen()
try:           
    url=myopener.open('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'+ij+'/?access_token=641567093.1fb234f.a0ffbe574e844e1c818145097050cf33')
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:  // I want the change here
    data1.append('Private Account')
    data2.append('Private Account')
    data3.append('Private Account')
    continue
beta=json.load(url)
item=beta['data']['counts']
data1.append(item['media'])
data2.append(item['followed_by'])
data3.append(item['follows'])
```

I am using Python version 3.5.2. The main question is **If the loop runs and a particular call is blocked and getting this error, how to avoid it and keep running the next iterations? Also, if the account is private, I want to append "Private account" to the lists.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the code that is actually fetching the URL is within your custom type - "Myopen" (which is not shown). It also looks like its not throwing the HTTPError you are expecting since your "json.load" line is still being executed (and leading to the ValueError that *is* being thrown).

If you want your error handling block to fire, you would need to check the response status code to see if its != 200 within Myopen and throw the HTTPError you are expecting instead of whatever its doing now.

---

I'm not personally familiar with `FancyURLOpener`, but it looks like it supports a `getcode` method. Maybe try something like this instead of expecting an HTTPError:

```
url = myopener.open('yoururl')
if url.getcode() == 400:
  data1.append('Private Account')
  data2.append('Private Account')
  data3.append('Private Account')
  continue
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have used FancyURLopener   in this way `class Myopen(FancyURLopener):
 version='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36' `  This is a User-agent which I am using. I dont know in IDLE, I am getting value error but when in an API checking website apigee.com, the reaon for the error is shown as the json code which I have displayed here. I dont know what to do

Comment: Can you please help me out with how to check the response status code!=200 as you suggested?

Comment: It was absolutely correct! Thank You so much for the help. @wilcosprey